# MySQL Server installation issue

Tags: mysql, server, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install the Oracle MySQL Server and Workbench  on a server computer running Windows 2008. For some reason I just can't install it - can someone give there opinion on the problem - I am uploading pictures of the installation process.

[I downloaded the 32 15.8M version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXHAz.png)

[Agreed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sQ9D.png)

[Here is where the first problem appears. The only two options I can actually choose are Default and Custom . i chose Custom because the only thing I can install is MySQL for Excel..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlUV.png)

[Custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmHjz.png)

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eBLV.png)

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3mmk.png)

[And at the end there is nothing installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Oo9.png)

Comment: You could try by downloading the full version (not the web installer)

Answer (score 0):

After choosing the setup type and product features, Do you get a chance to see the attached screen? with all components downloaded? [installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Pqb.png)

If you could see that and click on execute the product must be installed. 
-Don't forget to check if 
*your account has Admin privileges to install.
*The machine in which you are trying to install has access to internet via installers
-If you still face the problem i would suggest you to download the file of size 230MB and try installation with that.